# How to add Textview inside tab item? and i getting nullPointerException in setCustomView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

[image]

How to add TextView below tab item title .i want to 20 out of 50 completed below Me title of tabitem is it possible to do this. thanks in advance
I have done some of the solutions answered.but i got nullPointerException

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/userTabitem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/man_user"
            android:text="@string/username"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

**tabitem.xml**

custom tab for tabLayout

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/man_user"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabTitle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorOnTab"
    android:text="@string/username"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderdetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="50 out of 100"
    android:textColor="#B169D4"
    />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public void createTabItems() {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabitem,null);
        ImageView customImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tabIcon);
        customImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.man_user);
        TextView tabTitile=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabTitle);
        tabTitile.setText(R.string.username);
        TextView orderDetails=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.orderdetails);
        orderDetails.setText(R.string.orderdetails);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view));

    }
```

getting an error in the last line that setCustomView above method

**Logcat**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.android.saffrondesigner.MainActivity.createTabItems(MainActivity.java:148)
        at com.example.android.saffrondesigner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: have a look at -->https://mobikul.com/make-custom-tabs-icons-android/

Comment: @Wini thanks wini , i got nullpointerexception in setcustomview. what shoud i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your custom layout you wish like to set then do the following

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_layout));
```

**UPDATE**

This is custom layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#fff">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
 var customView1= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null)
        var primaryText1= customView1.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.primary)
        var secondaryText1=   customView1.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.secondary)



        var customView2= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null)
        var primaryText2= customView2.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.primary)
        var secondaryText2= customView2.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.secondary)



        primaryText1.text="ME"
        primaryText2.text="All"


        secondaryText1.text="20 out of completed"
        secondaryText2.text="100 out of completed"


        primaryText1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_icon1,0,0,0)
        primaryText2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_icon2,0,0,0)



        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(customView1));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(customView2));
```

Comment: could you please elaborate how to do it i am new to android development

Comment: thanks for your . but i have issue in setCustomView throws nullPointerException

Comment: in which method you're putting this code? and is this activity or fragment?

Comment: I have edited my question that I face hope you understand

Comment: have you initialize tablayout?

Comment: yes I initialized tablayout , tabLayout=(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

Comment: can you also add your mainactivity code on question section?

Comment: [github](https://github.com/ziyadrahman/orderbook) this my project could you please look this if you can

Comment: initialize tablayout  before createTabItems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204206/discussion-between-vikas-rai-and-ziyad-rahman).

Answer (score 0):

Create a TextView from Java Code or XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/tabs_default_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Make sure to keep the id as it is here because the TabLayout check for this ID if you use custom textview

Then from code inflate this layout and set the custom Typeface on that textview and add this custom view to the tab

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
 //noinspection ConstantConditions
 TextView tv = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null)
 tv.setTypeface(Typeface);       
 tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this xml code, Here you can define custom tabs without using custom xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/man_user"
        android:text="@string/username" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```